# prepare AD command of power shell is stuck in copy of files in first time

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, psexec

I run below powershell command through psexec for prepare Active Directory for install exchange server:

> .\Setup.exe /PrepareAD /OrganizationName:$Exchange_org_Name
>   /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms

But, it got stuck in first time during copy of files. When I run same command manually then its working fine. It prepared AD successfully.

Comment: But some times it works fine in first time also.Issue comes intermittently.

Comment: Message Comes after run above command-Files Copy Complete.Setup Will now collect additional information needed for installation.After that stuck process